# can't stop while loop going to the top of code in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

I have written a code in which i am using while loop.Inside this while loop I am executing a SOLR database query and until I get the result I want it to be inside the while loop.

Here is small part of the code.

```
def main_code():
  START_OF_THE_CODE

  count = 0
  while True:
    get_data = requests.get(solr_data)
    count += 1
    if get_data.status_code == 200 or count == 10:
       break

  REMANING CODE
```

The problem here is, when the query is not successful the first time, it checks the while condition and executes the query once again and during the execution it directly jumps to the START_OF_THE_CODE and starts executing the entire code again. I don't know what i am doing wrong.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "not successful"? Any error output? Any exception? Is your `main_code` function called in a loop?

Comment: Unless you have something running in a different thread/process that calls `main_code()` there is no way to get to the 'START_OF_THE_CODE' point in your code.

Comment: The only way `START_OF_THE_CODE` can run after the while loop is entered is if you run `main_code` again. What you're describing isn't possible without something else going on.

Comment: By not successful i mean it does't return status_code as 200 which is what i want. So unless and until i don't get status_code as 200 I run the query.